# In SciPy, what is 'slinear' interpolation?

Tags: python, scipy

I can't find an explanation [in the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d) or anywhere online. What does 'slinear' stand for and what does it do?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Looking at the source of `scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py`,
`slinear` is a [spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29) of order 1

```
if kind in ['zero', 'slinear', 'quadratic', 'cubic']:
    order = {'nearest': 0, 'zero': 0,'slinear': 1,
             'quadratic': 2, 'cubic': 3}[kind]
    kind = 'spline'
```

...

```
if kind in ('linear', 'nearest'):
    # Make a "view" of the y array that is rotated to the interpolation
    # axis.
    minval = 2
    if kind == 'linear':
        self._call = self._call_linear
    elif kind == 'nearest':
        self.x_bds = (x[1:] + x[:-1]) / 2.0
        self._call = self._call_nearest
else:
    minval = order + 1
    self._call = self._call_spline
    self._spline = splmake(x, y, order=order)
```

Since the docs for `splmake` state:

```
def splmake(xk, yk, order=3, kind='smoothest', conds=None):
    """
    Return a representation of a spline given data-points at internal knots
    ...
```

Comment: You beat me to it. I came up with the same conclusion.

Comment: @NilsWerner Though if both of us had to resort to the source, it's a good indication that the docs are incomplete.

Comment: When might one choose `slinear` over `linear`? A very brief test shows `linear` to be faster and returns the same result.

Comment: @Hooked, I have just posted a pull request to the main repo that fixes this oversight.

Comment: @KylerBrown they aren't actually the same... here's a gist showing the difference: https://gist.github.com/stringfellow/8ae4d3f25ca525e75bb79c01fbda4a24

Comment: @StevePike Thanks! So not the same but, within reasonable tolerances (floating point error?). Nice to have my question answered after four years!