# linearly extrapolate pandas dataframe using built-in interpolate method

Tags: pandas, interpolation, extrapolation

Consider the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([np.nan, np.nan,1, 5,np.nan, 6, 6.1 , np.nan,np.nan])
```

I would like to use the `pandas.DataFrame.interpolate` method to linearly extrapolate the dataframe entries at the starting and ending rows, similar to what I get if I do the following:

```
from scipy import interpolate
df_num = df.dropna()
xi = df_num.index.values
yi = df_num.values[:,0]
f = interpolate.interp1d(xi, yi, kind='linear', fill_value='extrapolate')
x = [0, 1 , 7, 8]
print(f(x))
[-7.  -3. 6.2 6.3]
```

It seems that the 'linear' option in pandas `interpolate` calls numpy's interpolate method which doesn't do linear extrapolation.  Is there a way to call the built-in interpolate method to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use scipy interpolate method directly in pandas. See [pandas.DataFrame.interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) documentation, you can use in `method` option techniques from *scipy.interpolate.interp1d* as it's noted in the attached link.

Solution for your example could look like:

```
df.interpolate(method="slinear", fill_value="extrapolate", limit_direction="both")

# Out: 
#      0
# 0 -7.0
# 1 -3.0
# 2  1.0
# 3  5.0
# 4  5.5
# 5  6.0
# 6  6.1
# 7  6.2
# 8  6.3
```

You can then easily select any values you are interested in, e.g. `df_interpolated.loc[x]` (where `df_interpolated` is output of the previous code block) using indexes defined in your question by `x` variable.

Explanation:

- **`method="slinear"`** - one of the method listed in pandas doc above that is passed to scipy `interp1d` (see e.g. [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572390/in-scipy-what-is-slinear-interpolation))
- **`fill_value="extrapolate"`** - pass any option allowed by scipy (here extrapolate which is exactly what you want)
- **`limit_direction="both"`** -  to get extrapolation in both direction (otherwise default would be set to "forward" in that case and you would see `np.nan` for the first two values)